# Smith isomorphism between the Spin and the Pin- bordism group

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, cobordism

> How to show the isomorphism between the following Spin and the Pin- bordism group, known as the Smith isomorphism:
>
> $$
> \Omega^{Spin}_{d}(B\mathbb{Z}_2)' \to \Omega^{Pin-}_{d-1}(pt)
> $$

in particular, the $\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(B\mathbb{Z}_2)'$ is not exactly the the usual Spin bordism group $\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(B\mathbb{Z}_2)'$, but the reduction.

Hint: One need to first show a relation:
$$
\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(BG)=\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(BG)' \oplus \Omega^{Spin}_{d}(pt)
$$
where the reduction of the spin bordism group $\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(BG)$ to $\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(BG)'$ gets rid of the $\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(pt)$. This part has something to do with the kernel of the forgetful map to $\Omega^{Spin}_{d}(pt)$.

> I like to understand what role does this forgetful map play, and how does the reduction help us to achieve the Smith isomorphism?